# What does this group of symbols mean?

Tags: puzzle-identification, symbols

This is what the puzzle looks like.

---

Ꮒ̨̻̰̊̾ͥͦ͠Ꮛ̤̰̭̱̑̔̃̽̋ͬᏒ̡̼̯̳̺̳̺̙͖͈̠̂ ̗̗̗͔̮̀̾̉̃ͩ̿ͤᏁ̱̗͈̰̙̥̪́͊̅̎̅Ꮧ̵͚̥̼̫ͬ̒ͨ̏̅Ꮇ̥͉̂͛ͥ͛̽͐̕͟Ꮛ̨̫̭̋͛̆̋̾

---

What do they mean? It should be a name.

Comment: Looks like [zalgo text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6579844/how-does-zalgo-text-work). If you clean it up a bit using [some online tool](https://github.kdex.de/unzalgo/) it looks like `ᏂᏋᏒ ᏁᏗᎷᏋ`. "her name"?

Comment: @Poke You might want to ROT13 that

Comment: @GrumpyLlama59 I'll keep that in mind for next time. Based on the `puzzle-identification` tag I figured he was asking for help

Answer (score 1):

What I've got so far...

> When translated from zalgo text it becomes ᏋᏂᏒ ᏁᏗᎷᏋ which are Cherokee characters quv-ni-sv ne-di-lu-quv